# ASP.NET WebApi with Entity Framework - connect to database under different users

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have project in ASP.NET WebAPI (web service), which serves a web site and connects to a SQL Server database using Entity Framework.

Entity Framework is connecting to database under one login, which is stored in `config` file. But I must connect to database under login and password, which a user filled on the website, and execute all the queries under this user(user must have his own session on SQL Server).

Could anyone tell me whether it is possible or not? And if it possible, should I realise this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems you have to dynamically generate the connection string for each user as the use the website. I doubt EntityFramework (or any other ORM) can handle that. They usually take the connection string when first configuring it and just use the same thing all over the place.

Comment: @Alejandro all ORMs allow you to change the connection settings at runtime or provide a new connection string when creating a new context/session. Otherwise it would be impossible to test them

Comment: *Why* connect using different accounts? Are you creating a multi-tenant service? There are better ways to handle this. For example, why not have a different database per client?

Answer (score 0):

If the user sends the username and the password in the request to the WebAPI then you need to generate the connection string yourself dynamically and then use it to connect to the database.

Other option, you can configure kerberos authentication on the webapi and then add some logic into the database based on SYSTEM_USER parameter. Or depending on the sql server version you can use Role Based Security

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017